# How to continuously send GPS data to a service?

Tags: architecture, gps, client-server

Let's say that I have a device which has to report the data from a device's GPS sensor to a server.

In other words, the server needs to know the coordinates of the device at any point in the time.

What is the best way of updating the GPS coordinates of a device on a server?

Should the server ask the device about its coordinates periodically (for example, every N seconds)? Or maybe the device should initiate a GPS data update every N seconds and send the data to the server?

What is the best industry practice of continuous and permanent GPS coordinates updating between a client and a server?

Answer (score 3):

are you doing Android Application ? In Android Application I have done same thing, Here I am using TimerTask class that sends lat-long to server on a particular time period.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/SchedulingaTimerTasktoRunRepeatedly.htm) is a link of example of TimerTask Class. you need to put your uploading code in to its run method.

Comment: No, I am not using Android, my question is general.

Comment: Lucifer, it is a desktop Java application, which has to report its coordinates to a web server.

Comment: But how can you get GPS inside the room or office ? for fetching GPS your device must be outside or near to window atleast

Comment: Lucifer, it is a 'desktop' application on a standard PC which is inside a vehicle (sorry for being vague with descriptions). The PC has a USB GPS antenna.

Comment: HEY Martin lee thats beautiful having pc in vehicle which has an usb GPS Antena really beautiful :) 
u solved my problem.